# Disable PushRow deselection

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms, deselect

This is a question about the library, [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/).

I have a `PushRow` with a number of options(names). And I also set the first item of those options as the one selected by default upon initialization.

var names = ["Jake", "Cassie", "Rachel", "Marco", "Ax", "Tobias"]

```
<<< PushRow<WindowStyle>("NamesRow") {
        $0.title = "Names"
        $0.options = names
        $0.value = names.first
    }
```

I run the app and *Jake* is selected by default as expected. If I tap on the `PushRow` and reselect *Jake* and now it gets deselected. This is expected behavior, I assume. But I want to avoid deselection if I tap on an already selected option row.

The `row` property in `onChange` callback closure returns `nil` if the same option gets selected. I tried to do a nil check and exit early but it doesn't work. It seems `onChange` method is fired after all that deselection happens.

```
.onChange { row in
    guard let selectedName = row.value else {
        return
    }
}
```

How can I disable deselection?

Comment: Found any solution?

Comment: @korgx9 Unfortunately no. Your best bet is opening an issue on their repo.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you've found an answer for this.

And, although I haven't done this myself, I'd like to point in the right direction.

They have included it in their update to Swift 3.

Please find the same at, https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/261#issuecomment-255439929

And just for reference,

```
.onPresent { form, selectorController in
         selectorController.enableDeselection = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit older, but if someone is still looking for the answer:
You can do this with:

```
}.onPresent { form, row in
                row.enableDeselection = false}
```